# How did the Coen Brothers come to their arrangement for sharing credit?

Tags: directors, coen-brothers

This book by Robert Schnakenberg I am reading says that the

> inspiration came from the 1965 comedy Boeing-Boeing - in which the
> names of top-billed stars Jerry Lewis and Tony Curtis rotate on an
> axis during the opening credits

With a quick Google search, I am unable to find any other site online that says the same (or for that matter, anything different).

Is the above a credible reference?

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coen_brothers#Directing_distinctions

Comment: Have a look at the IMDb page for "No country for old men". The two names keep swapping on the page. Compare with Fargo (1996), the names are reversed! Nice team work, and a good way to keep a family united.